# How can I have a textarea or some text input in a table row, and allow it to expand on click or drag, without increasing row height?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I basically just want the textarea to be able to grow or expand on click or drag, and not have it modify the height of the table row. Here is an example on code pen of the problem:

https://codepen.io/kerastensorflow/pen/PobaRvK?editors=1010

```
        <Table>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 5</th>
         </tr>
          <tr style = {{maxHeight:"50px"}}>
            <td><input style = {{width:"100px"}} readonly/></td>
            <td><input style = {{width:"150px"}}/></td>
            <td><input style = {{width:"150px"}}/></td>
            <td><input style = {{width:"80px"}} /></td>
            <td><textarea></textarea></td>
          </tr>
        </Table>
```

Comment: `textarea{position: absolute,top: 0;left: 0}` and make parent of text area `position: relative`

Comment: Adding position may not be correct way. this will be difficult in case of multiple row. textarea will overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this hack.

```css
.div {
  height : 60px;
  width:200px;
  overflow : auto;
}
```

```html
        <Table>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 5</th>
          </tr>
          <tr style = {{maxHeight:"50px"}}>
            <td><input style = {{width:"100px"}} readonly/></td>
            <td><input style = {{width:"150px"}}/></td>
            <td><input style = {{width:"150px"}}/></td>
            <td><input style = {{width:"80px"}} /></td>
            <td><div class="div"><textarea></textarea></div></td>
          </tr>
          
        </Table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add position: absolute for the textarea